# Principal Component Analysis

Tags: pca

I am doing PCA using Matlab's pca() function and R's prcomp() function. They give identical principal components in some cases and  same values and opposite sign in some other cases. Why is this happening? 
P.S : I am not asking about the interpretation.

Comment: By "exactly opposite", do you mean that the values are the same but the signs flip?

Comment: yes...the coefficients and scores have the same values but the signs flip